# How do i translate PROC MIXED in SAS to R with gls? (MMRM, AR1)

Tags: r, sas, mixed-models

I am trying to get the same result as sas with R but there seems to be some difficulties.

For example
R: contras:2-1 AVISITN = 6: estimate is -1.81 and SE is 1.59

```
library(nlme)
library(emmeans) 
gls <- do.call("gls", list(data=data,
                           model=CHG~TRTPN+AVISITN+TRTPN*AVISITN+BASE+COUNTRY,
                           correlation=corAR1(form=~1|SUBJID),
                           weights=varIdent(form=~1|AVISITN), method="REML" )) 
emm <- emmeans(gls, specs=trt.vs.ctrl ~ TRTPN, at=list(AVISITN=c(6,7,8,9,10)),
               by = "AVISITN", level = 0.4) summary(emm)
```

SAS:
estimate is -1.2 and SE is 1.24

```
proc mixed data=data method=reml;
  class subjid avisit trtp country ;
  model chg = trtp avisit trtpavisit country base /CL SOLUTION DDFM=KR; repeated avisit / subject=subjid type=AR(1) r;
  lsmeans trtpavisit / PDIFF CL alpha=0.40;
  ODS output Diffs=diffs01 lsmeans=lsmeans01;
run;
```

I have very little experience in using R so is there a way to get the same result? Many many thanks!

Comment: SAS:proc mixed data=data method=reml; 
     class subjid avisit   trtp   country ;
     model chg = trtp avisit  trtp*avisit country base    /CL SOLUTION DDFM=KR;
     repeated avisit /  subject=subjid  type=AR(1) r;  
     lsmeans trtp*avisit / PDIFF CL alpha=0.40;
     ODS output 
         Diffs=diffs01
         lsmeans=lsmeans01;        
run;

Comment: R: library(nlme)
library(emmeans)
gls <- do.call("gls", 
list(data=data,
model=CHG~TRTPN+AVISITN+TRTPN*AVISITN+BASE+COUNTRY,
correlation=corAR1(form=~1|SUBJID),
weights=varIdent(form=~1|AVISITN),
method="REML"
))
emm <- emmeans(gls, specs=trt.vs.ctrl ~ TRTPN, at=list(AVISITN=c(6,7,8,9,10)), 
by = "AVISITN", level = 0.4)
summary(emm)

Answer (score 1):

with the new `mmrm` package this is easy, and you will get results very close to SAS results:

```r
library(mmrm)
library(emmeans) 
fit <- mmrm(
  CHG ~ TRTPN + AVISIT + TRTPN * AVISIT + BASE + COUNTRY + ar1(AVISIT | SUBJID),
  data = data,
  method = "Kenward-Roger"
)
summary(fit)
```

Note that instead of a numeric `AVISITN` variable you should use the factor `AVISIT` variable with `mmrm`.
And the `emmeans` code can be used identically.

Does that help?